# Creating a 3D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement a 3D array in Java but I've a problem, my problem is that I don't know one of the lengths of 3D array size, it means that third length of my 3D is variable and it depends on
the input size. In other words my 3D array called

```
int arcbits[64][1][length(input)];
```

first two sizes are fixed, it's always `[64][1]` and just the third length is variable.

`length(input)` is always positive integer greater zero.
Input is like this `form = {1,0,1,1}`, so in this case for instance the arcbits size is:

```
int arcbits[64][1][4];
```

How do I implement that in Java? My problem is that there's a variable length which for instance in `c++` or `c` we do dynamic allocation ...because we don't know the size of the array. So do I do 3D array in Java with implicitly variable size?!

I'm stuck on this about two days and I didn't succeed to implement 3D array in Java, this is the first time I counter this, any suggestion to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][][] arcbits = new int[64][1][length(input)];
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: but my problem is that in java I can'y initiate an array with variable length no? for instance in c I must have the length of the array as fixed length in order to initiate it , otherwise I would do it dynamically..it sounds like java is different. Anyway, to use what you write musn't I import any java library?

Comment: @TonyVany You can initialize an array with variable length. No, you don't need to import anything. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes , but it sounds the problem in my eclipse

Comment: Solved ! , thanks alot (error from compiler itself

Comment: @TonyVany No problem.

Comment: I will not mind, it takes two days to start accepting ..because Im new here(just before two hour made my account)

Comment: @TonyVany You need to loop over it. You could use streams, e.g. `IntStream.rangeClosed(i, i + 5).map(i -> received[i]).toArray();`

Comment: @TonyVany Generally, it is better to ask new questions for these.

Comment: ofcourse wouldn't be anything else , just regard to IntStream issue

Comment: @TonyVany What is the issue?

Comment: You need to `import java.util.stream.*;`

Comment: no need for sending me messages :) I will go to your advice to post the question, I posted a new question in order to not messing this thread up. thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see here:
[Sum in Java (built in method)'s Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575448/sum-in-java-built-in-methods-implementation/65575621#65575621)

I already declared 3d array in java, I guess you look on the same concept.

Comment: @iota could you please help me in my that?